# Configure manual updates in Firefox 75

Tags: firefox, ubuntu-20.04

I have just installed Ubuntu 20.04, and Firefox 75 within it.
I cannot find how to configure updates in FF, in particular to instruct FF not to perform automatic updates.
This is what I see.

[image]

**Is there any way to get back that configuration option in the Preferences menu?**

**EDIT**:
A couple of alternatives were posted as answers. They appear very useful, even if not addressing exactly the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
apt-mark 
    apt-mark can be used as a unified front-end to set various settings for
    a package, such as marking a package as being automatically/manually
    installed or changing dpkg selections such as hold, install, deinstall
    and purge which are respected e.g. by apt-get, dselect-upgrade or aptitude.
hold
    hold is used to mark a package as held back, which will prevent the
    package from being automatically installed, upgraded or removed.
```

Hold a package:

```
sudo apt-mark hold <package-name>
```

Unhold a package:

```
sudo apt-mark unhold <package-name>
```

Show all packages on hold:

```
sudo apt-mark showhold
```

Comment: Interesting. Is the process initiated by the Firefox update the same as what `apt` does?
I wonder if this answer would actually prevent FF updates.
In addition, this may be an exact equivalent, or a workaround, for preventing FF builtin updates.
I am more interested in recovering the option via Preferences, though.

Comment: The process is of updating Firefox is normally handled by apt as a back-end and apt-mark integrates with apt and modifies the default settings for under what conditions `apt upgrade` is permitted to upgrade a specific package.

Comment: The options now in the about:config section is the new way of setting things like this to keep Firefox more automatic for most people

Comment: Those options are useful for Windows users, however in Ubuntu Firefox is installed by default and upgrading Firefox is handled by `apt`, not by the options in the `about:config` section of Firefox. Furthermore package management for all .deb packages in the default Ubuntu repositories is handled by apt and package management for all snap packages in the default Ubuntu repositories is handled by snap.

Comment: I tested the above in my Ubuntu machine and it works the same way.

Comment: One thing I just tested is using `sudo apt-mark hold firefox`.
Then I checked `about:config` -> `app.update.auto` and it is still set to `True` as shown [in this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1547947/245595), so the integration does not get **that** far.
I do not mean this won't work, anyway.

Comment: It is pure chaos to use a different package management interface for each package in Ubuntu. There is no good reason to make a perfectly simple package management system so complicated. Instead use one package management tool for everything.

Comment: If I remember correctly, there was more than one option in Preferences (and I found the options very adequate). Something like "Automatic", "Download and ask to install", and "Never", or the like.
I see this very convenient, and not complicated at all.
What would the equivalent via `sudo apt-mark` be, if any?
And if I remember correctly, `apt-get install firefox` still updated ok, so I do not see any problem with keeping both methods.

Comment: The equivalent options in apt-mark are auto, manual, showauto and showmanual. To show all the options for apt-mark run `man apt-mark` in the terminal.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu, in Firefox, in the address bar, type about:config and enter. Accept the risks, Show All, scroll down for app.update.auto.  Change this to false.

I do NOT recommend this because (a) there is no harm in updating, and (b) changes here could have unintended consequences.

Comment: As I understand, this is what is actually under the hood when the option was available via Preferences, and therefore the result would be equivalent. I am more interested in recovering the option via Preferences, though (if possible at all).
Moreover, if I remember correctly, there was more than one option (and I found the options very adequate). Something like "Automatic", "Download and ask to install", and "Never", or the like. What would the equivalent via about:config be?